# Force sign-out of all Visual Studio 2013 instances on remote machines

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm leaving my internship in a few weeks and have signed in to Visual Studio on a few machines here, some that I no longer have access to.

I can't find a page online that lets me remotely sign-out of all Visual Studio deployments on all machines. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'd be interested to know if there is a way to do this as well.  Worst case, you could change your password.  I believe that would stop your account being used on any of the other machines.

Comment: @Calcolat, interestingly, changing my password did not sign me out, at least not immediately.